# ExtJS: open an item directly with URL

Tags: extjs

With REST we can easily navigate, for example, to a user like `myApp/user/1`

I was wondering, we can do it also with ExtJS?

My motivation for this is that I want an external application to open my ExtJS application on a specific item, for example, user with id 1

I tried Router, but when I open a new window with the hash `#user/1` it does not open the user. It works if I open my application and then add the hash `#user/1` to the URL. It can be something on my app preventing from working?

Comment: Router is the right tool for this, look up documentation, if you set it up right, it exactly does what you need.

Comment: Peter is right. [Here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/guides/application_architecture/router.html) is the link. And [Here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3ee3) is a fiddle showing the routes in detail.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I found that we already have a route for what I want and it is working